# SummernoteInplaceWidget Not Working Properly - summernote-lite

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, summernote

I have recently discovered Summernote and love it.  I have run into a problem where when I am using it in my django installation, the SummernoteWidget is working but the SummernoteInplaceWidget is not.  When I use the SummernoteWidget, the data appears in my editor as I would expect, but when I use the SummernoteInplaceWidget, I get a blank screen.  Thanks for any thoughts.  My code...

I am using Summernote-Lite without bootstrap and I am using the most recent version 0.8.9

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.js"></script>
```

My Summernote_Config in settings.py

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = { 
   'summernote': {
        'toolbar': [
          ['undo', ['undo',]],
          ['redo', ['redo',]],
          ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline',]],
          ['font', ['strikethrough',]],
          ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ],
        'width': 760,
        'height': 300,
        'focus': True,
        'fontSizes': ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '18', '22','24', '36', '48' , '64', '82', '150'],
},
}
```

My CSS...

```
.editor {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 24.4rem;
}
```

My widget reference in forms.py..

```
widgets = {
   'book': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
}
```

The editor renders, but I just get a blank screen...

[image]

If I use the SummernoteWidget instead,

```
widgets = {
   'book': SummernoteWidget(),
}
```

My CSS....

```
.editor {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 24.4rem;
}
```

I get the data on the screen that I'm expecting, but font size setting is not honored as shown below.

[image]

Any ideas on if this is a bug or if I'm doing something incorrectly which is entirely possible?  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @solarissmoke Thank  you for the input.  No errors on the console.  The editor render as I would expect, but no errors indicating a missing library or anything of that nature.  No errors at all.

Comment: Curiously enough, read that Boostrap default font-size is 14px....perhaps the Summernote-lite version is still somehow referencing Bootstrap default even though this version isn't supposed to require Bootstrap...Still troubleshooting..

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AreebaSeher Sadly no.  I wound up using TinyMCE instead.  It was more flexible and a little easier to get working.  Sorry I don't have better news for you.

Comment: @SteveSmith No worries. Yes, TinyMCE, CKEditor 4, and 5 are more flexible and easy to integrate and have more features as compared to summernote.